# some bones don't follow a rig controller

Tags: rigging

[image]hi I put rigfy on this chicken and for some reason feet bones doesn't follow the rig controller...
what causes you can think about? [image]

Comment: Sometimes when your armature and model have different scales and the new scales are not applied, then some bones might not be assigned any weight. To solve this go into Object Mode, select the rig and your model and then Ctrl+A and 'All Transforms'.

Comment: I tried that too and it still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, the rig is behaving as it should.

By default, the legs are in IK, and the feet are independant from the body movement. So the rig stretches the legs. If this is not what you want, you should have options displayed in the sidebar when a leg controller is selected.

A real issue in your case though: the bottom part of the leg mesh seems to be incorrectly skinned to the rig. Ideally the leg should stretch with the rig, I guess the bottom part of your leg isn't assigned to the feet deform bone, hence it just detaches itself from the feet.
You should go in weight paint mode and paint the bottom row of vertices to your feet weight groups.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understanding what you suggested at the beginning... but I checked weight and it's painted on feet too.  I just found out that when I generated rigfy, it made another rig on the chicken and it looks quite weird. and it is separated in "root" and "MCH torso parent". feet are belonging to root. Is this normal? I'll put the picture in my post

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I deleted some bones that I shouldn't have... I tried a new armature and rigify again and the feet followed the control!